# PHP MVC How to go from view back to the original controller

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I´´m trying to build my first PHP MVC application and I´m having problems going from the view back to the controller.

My problem is in the view, when I need to enter data and go back to the original controller that called the view, but with a different action (to validate the data entry).

I have this code in my view:

```
        <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>">
        <label>Username:</label> 
        <input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo $username;?>"> <br> <br> <label>Password:</label>
        <input type="password" name="password"> 
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
```

That view is called from my controller:

```
class HomeController {

        public function index () 
        {
            $parameters = (func_num_args() >= 1) ? func_get_arg(0) : array();

            require_once(ROOTPATH . '/controller/class.Render.php');

            $variables = array(
                    'username' => '',
                    'password' => '',
                    'errorMsg' => ''
            );      

            $layout = new Render("Home", "login", $variables);
        }
    }
```

And my render:

```
class Render 
{
    private $controller;

    private $view;

    public function __construct ($controller, $view, $variables = array()) 
    {
        $this->controller = strtolower($controller); 
        $this->view = strtolower($view); 

        $filename = ROOTPATH . '/view/' . $this->controller . '/' . $this->view . '.php';
        if (!file_exists($filename))
        {
            $errorMsg = "ERROR: View not found on Layout construct: " . $filename;
            throw new Exception($errorMsg);
        }

        if (count($variables) > 0) {
            foreach ($variables as $key => $value) {
                if (strlen($key) > 0) {
                    ${$key} = $value;
                }
            }
        }

        echo "<body>";
        echo "<div class='container'>";
        echo "<div id='dialogDiv'></div>";

        require_once(ROOTPATH . '/view/header.php');
        require_once ($filename);
        require_once(ROOTPATH . '/view/footer.php');

        echo "</div>";
        echo "</body>";
    } 
}
```

My problem is that,  when I click `submit` in the form it calls the `index` controller - the `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` shows the `index` page, not the `home/index` page.

If I change the `form action` to `action='home/index'`, it will give me an error that `index/home/index` page does not exist...

How can I go to my submit back to my original controller to process the data entry ?

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Change action to: `action='/home/index'` with a leading slash. Without the leading slash `home/index` will be appended to the current url as you stated -> `index/home/index `.

Comment: It tells /home/index does not exist (and it does not exist as well). This problem seens not be related to the action parameter, but to code structure.

Comment: How is the pattern of the raw url without mod_rewrite? Something like: `index.php?controller=home&action=index`?